# Adjust anchor to other pages with a fixed menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a website with a menu fixed on top. At the home page, I have  tags that should anchor to id's from other pages on my website. The anchor to these id's work fine, however, the top part of their content stays behind the fixed menu.

I tried to solve it by using JavaScript animate method and adding the menu's height value. This works well when the anchor's destiny id is from the same page. But it doesn't work in my case, because I want to go to an id in another page from the website.

My **HTML**:

```
<a href="http://localhost/meu_site/psicologia#psicoterapia" class="psi-block-item"></a>
```

My **JavaScript**:

```
<script src="http://localhost/meu_site/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

$('.psi-block-item').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("href")
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-100 }, 100)
})
```

Apparently, when jumping from the home page to another page, it seems to ignore my last js command and just follow the href, keeping part of the content behind the fixed menu.

I already saw some people suggesting to use pseudo css elements and hiding them to make it works, but I was looking for a clean and more professional solution, using only html and javascript.

Thank y'all.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable the page is reloaded before it can execute the code. Therefore I would suggest that you include a window onload event listener to every page that looks for the hash and then executes your animation.

***EDIT:***
Please see the answer by @nengak-dakup. His answer looks pretty good.
The implementation would look like this.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="page1.html#anchor1">Link to Page1 - Anchor 1</a>
        <a href="page1.html#anchor2">Link to Page1 - Anchor 2</a>
        <a href="page1.html#anchor3">Link to Page1 - Anchor 3</a>
    </header>
</body>
```

and page1.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: grey;
            z-index: 5;
        }
        .box {
            position: relative;
            top: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).load(function() {
            var target = this.location.href;
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-100 }, 100);
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">Back</a>
    </header>
    <div id="anchor1" class="box" style="background-color: blue"></div>
    <div id="anchor2" class="box" style="background-color: green"></div>
    <div id="anchor3" class="box" style="background-color: red"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I agree that the problem can be the page being reloaded before it can execute the code. But I don't understand your suggestion. How a window onload will help me if I want to use the "click" event to trigger the action to go to the other page?

Comment: I updated my comment with a working example. You have to include the onload logic from @nengak-dakup into every page where you need the anchor functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).load(function() {
    var target = this.location.href;
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-100 }, 100);
})
```

i'm not sure, but this should be the logic to work it out...

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand.

If I want to click some element to go to other page at a specific point, why I would call the action with a (document).load?

In my example, I started it with the click on the element I want to click to get the result. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Youre using document.load so when the page loads, you check the URL of the page, then scroll to the particular element.